# How to exclude project from multi module Maven License Plugin aggregation?

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, license-maven-plugin

I'm having trouble trying to ignore some modules when I add headers to my files using maven license plugin. The way I am trying to do is to put the modules path in the excludes tag. Here is the plugin in pom.xml:

```
    <plugin>
            <groupId>com.mycila.maven-license-plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-license-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.b1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>format</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <header>header.txt</header>
                        <aggregate>true</aggregate>
                        <excludes>          
                            <exclude>**/a/**</exclude>
                            <exclude>**/b/**</exclude>
                            <exclude>**/c/**</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

This is the way I'm trying to ignore the projects inside this parent pom.xml. I have already tried also with
 ${project.basedir}/a/
and 
${basedir}/a/

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
<excludes>          
   <exclude>a/**</exclude>
   <exclude>b/**</exclude>
   <exclude>c/**</exclude>
</excludes>
```

Comment: Sadly, no luck on this.